# Unexpected zsh global alias expansion

Tags: zsh, zsh-alias

EDIT: The example works in pure zsh. My installation with prezto won't work. Seems like a bug in prezto.

I tried to alias `sponge` as `SP` in zsh. But the result is pretty surprising.

Without global alias:

```
❯ echo xxx >! xxx
❯ cat xxx | sponge xxx
❯ cat xxx  # non-empty file
xxx
```

With global alias:

```
❯ echo xxx >! xxx
❯ alias -g SP='| sponge '
❯ cat xxx SP xxx
❯ cat xxx
(empty file, no lines are shown here)
```

What's the cause of the strange behavior? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

you are replacing what should be a pipe with an argument

```
cat xxx SP xxx
```

means that cat now has 3 arguments

```
alias -g SP='sponge'
```

and

```
cat xxx | SP
```

Should give you desired results